# How to disable and enable a button dynamically?

Tags: c#, xaml, button, uwp

In my UWP, I have a `TextBox` and a `Button.` I want to disable the `Button` when the `TextBox` is empty.

I tried this on startup-

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmmtxtBox.Text))
{
    hmmbtn.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

---

```
private void HmmtxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    hmmbtn.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

It works kind of okay, but when I clear the `TextBox`, the `Button` remains enabled. I want to disable if the `TextBox` is empty and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void HmmtxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    hmmbtn.IsEnabled = HmmtxtBox.Text.Length > 0;
}
```